# Generating Custom Exceptions

Tags: python, exception, pep8

My module raises certain exception when something, not necessarily bad, happens. However, when importing the module I am hoping to do something like this to import them all:

```
from MyModule import MyModuleExceptions
```

Currently the way I'm generating the exceptions is via this function:

```
def gen_exceptions():
    EXCEPTION_TYPES = (
        "FirstException",           # scenario 1
        "SecondException",          # scenario 2
        "UnexpectedException"       # Everything else
    )
    MyModuleExceptionsFactory = namedtuple("exceptions", EXCEPTION_TYPES)
    exceptions = {key: type(key, (Exception,), {}) for key in EXCEPTION_TYPES}

    return MyModuleExceptionsFactory(**exceptions)

MyModuleExceptions = gen_exceptions()
```

and in my module I can use it as:

```
try:
    # do stuff
except MyModuleExceptions.FirstException:
    # Handle scenario 1
except Exception:
    # Everything else
```

Is the correct way "Pythonic" way of doing it? Or is there a well-established practice that I should follow?

Comment: Probably instead of a `namedtuple` you could just use a `types.SimpleNamespace`. Not that a `namedtuple` doesn't work.

Comment: Did you get that code/approach from somewhere? I don't think I've seen custom exceptions created in that way before; there are much simpler ways but I couldn't say whether or not they are best practice or corner-cutting. I'd like to know more myself.

Comment: Also, is there some reason you aren't just writing class definitions and using dynamic class creation? It seems like your `EXCEPTION_TYPES` will be fixed, so, I wouldn't use a class-factory.

Comment: @roganjosh What simpler ways were you referring to?

Comment: Picked a small library off the top of my head: https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/exceptions.py basically just have a file for exceptions and a bunch of classes that inherit from `Exception`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Basically I would like to group the exceptions in a namespace inside the module. Writing separate class definitions seems redundant and I would not be able to import them all at once.

Comment: You _can_ import them all at once without referencing the individual exceptions. Put them in a `my_special_exceptions.py` file and in your main code just `import my_special_exceptions`. Any class inside that module is accessible: `raise(my_special_exceptions.dont_do_that)`

Comment: @roganjosh Hmm, I think you made a point and found an answer to my question, thanks.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Yeah, Exception class definitions often seem repetitive, but proper definitions are explicit, too, talking about pythonicity (also don't forget the IDE features like code completion/navigation/etc). You can still group them via module or by making them inner classes of another class.

Comment: @roganjosh If you can write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Im on my phone so code writing is tough. And also, im not sure whether thats _best practice_, only that you can do it and it will work. I haven't seen anything substantially different from that approach though.

Comment: If the exceptions are dynamically generated, how do you catch them?

Comment: @SergueuFedorov They are dynamically generated, but the list of exception names are predefined.